# Distribution of electric potential for a configuration of two concentric spherical conductors

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields, potential

I understand how to use Gauss Law to derive the expressions for the electric field at various radii, but I don't quite understand how the derivations for the electric potential work.

Why is it that, for r<R1, they use the expressions for E1,E2, and E3. But then right after that, for R1<r<R2, they only use E1 and E2 and then for r>R3, they use only the expression for E3?

Also how are the limits for the integration determined?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only requirements when determining the electric potential are that it should satisfy $\mathbf{E} = -\mathrm{\mathbf{grad}}V$ and be continuous at the interfaces. This means that it is defined up to a constant that you can choose freely, depending on your taste. Your book has chosen the constant such that the potential vanishes at infinity, but you can do it differently. I find their thing with the integration limits a little confusing though. If I were to do this calculation, I would write, from the integration of the electric field:
$$V_I(r) = C_I, \hspace{3pt} V_{II}(r) = \frac{Q_1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r} + C_{II}, \hspace{3pt} V_{III}(r) = \frac{Q_1+Q_2}{4\pi\varepsilon_0r}+C_{III}$$
Then, requiring a vanishing potential at infinity would set $C_{III}=0$, and you will find the exact same $C_I$ and $C_{II}$ as in your solution by solving the continuity equations $V_I(R_1) = V_{II}(R_1)$ and $V_{II}(R_2) = V_{III}(R_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I think might be the explanation:

Notice that the only non constant term is always the one that results from the integration of the respective electric field. The Integration over the other "outer" electric fields just gives you the right constant for them to coincide at $R_1$ and $R_2$. Concerning the reason for not considering the "outer" electric fields: The primary boundary condition is
\begin{align}
\phi(r)\longrightarrow 0 \,(r\longrightarrow \infty).
\end{align}
This sets the constant of the Potential for $r>R_2$, which can be seen as an additional boundary condition for smaller $r$. In short the primary boundary condition forces you to define your Potential at the radii from the outside in, only considering what you have defined so far (thus the outside fields).